# Can I know all shared folders with my account in network?

Tags: network-shares, shared-folders

I would know all share folders that I already had access permission to read, modify ...etc.

And if I would check any username permissions to list all share folders for them in the company network?

Thanks

Comment: We would need a complete network map of your work network to answer this. Much more information is needed to answer this correctly.

Comment: If you are part of the controlled environment, your IT admin should be able to give you that answer. Or you could use an IP scanner, I like "Advanced IP scanner" after scan He will show you advertised shares on the network and after that there is a manual work, you check every advertised share and see do you have access and if you do what are your rights there. If you give us more info about your environment, as Moab have asked before, maybe you could get a smarter answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open Computer management > System Tools > Shared Folders > Shares. Then the central panel will load all shares, including hidden administrative shares. Or you can right click and click Properties > Share permissions tab to know the permissions of users, including you. Using cmd you can use the command `net use` to view network shares which are active.

Comment: *net use* shows currently open connections, but not others that might be available on the network. It's a good start, though.

Comment: Ok @DrMoishePippik thank you

Comment: Dear, I don’t mean the local shared folders in the computer. For example, a user have access to multiple folders in the network of the company server. I need to check what exactly he can access ?